unable to deploy Azure Api management in the existingazure vnet subnet
I am trying to deploy the API management in the existing vnet subnet. Its an internal API management gateway stv2 so i have to provide the public IP as well as Public IP address is required to use availability zones since my service is in a virtual network".Other team has setup the required infrastructure already like vnets, subnets, Function APP etc.The issue is when i am trying to deploy API management with public IP it throws the error message. Kindly suggest how to fix this one?
Data block section
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "azdlgleuw-rg-sharatapigw-001"
}
    
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtualnetwork" {
  name                = "azdlgleuw-vnet-sharatapigw-001"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "apisubnet" {
  name                 = "azdlgleuw-snet-sharatapigw-001"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.virtualnetwork.name
}

Resource Block
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "api-pip" {
    allocation_method   = "Static"
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    name                = "azdlgleuw-pip-publicip-001"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    sku                 = "Standard"
    zones = [1,2,3]
    sku_tier                = "Regional"
    idle_timeout_in_minutes = 4
    ip_version              = "IPv4"
    domain_name_label   = "azure-api-sharatapigw-001"
}

Creating the API management resources
resource "azurerm_api_management" "apim" {
  name                 = "azdlgleuw-apim-apimngname-001"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location             = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  publisher_name       = "sharat"
  publisher_email      = "abc@xyz.com"
  virtual_network_type = "Internal"
  sku_name             = "Developer_1"

  virtual_network_configuration {
    subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.apisubnet.id
  }

  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.api-pip.id
}


resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi" {
  name                = "azdlgleuw-apim-apimgmntapi-001"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "sharat-api"
  path                = "extranet/v1"
  protocols           = ["https"]

  import {
    content_format = "openapi"
    content_value  = file("${path.module}/openapi.yaml")
  }  
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "example" {
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sharatapimgmntapi.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base />
    <set-backend-service base-url="https://azure-api-sharatapigw-001.azurewebsites.net/api" />
  </inbound>
</policies>
XML
}

Error message:

Error: creating/updating Service (Subscription: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
│ Resource Group Name: "azdlgleuw-rg-sharatapigw-001"
│ Service Name: "azure-api-sharatapigw-001"): performing CreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with error: InvalidParameters: Invalid parameter: When updating subnetResourceId to /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/azdlgleuw-rg-sharatapigw-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/azdlgleuw-vnet-sharatapigw-001/subnets/azdlgleuw-snet-sharatapigw-001 in API Management service deployment with Virtual Network configured Internal, the Public IP Address property in location West Europe, must be a different from /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/azdlgleuw-rg-sharatapigw-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/azdlgleuw-pip-publicip-001 and should not match any of the existing location(s) (West Europe), as we need to create a new deployment to avoid downtime.



Unable to deploy Azure Api management in the existing azure vnet subnet:


Verify that the previously created subnet and the currently being created API Management service are located in the same region before connecting the API Management service to the subnet. Both should be in the same region if you want to use the existed one.
Additionally, to deploy the API Management service into an existing subnet, it is necessary to have a Network security group associated with the subnet.


Note: Associate it through portal and then try deployment once again to get succeeded.
After checking above, I tried your requirement, and the deployment was successful as shown below.
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "jahresources"
}
    
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtualnetwork" {
  name                = "westvnet"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "apisubnet" {
  name                 = "default2west"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.virtualnetwork.name
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "api-pip" {
    allocation_method   = "Static"
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    name                = "azdlgleuw-pip-publicip-001"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    sku                 = "Standard"
    zones = [1,2,3]
    sku_tier                = "Regional"
    idle_timeout_in_minutes = 4
    ip_version              = "IPv4"
    domain_name_label   = "azure-api-sharatapigw-001"
}
resource "azurerm_api_management" "apim" {
  name                 = "azdlgleuw-apim-apijah-001"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location             = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  publisher_name       = "sharat"
  publisher_email      = "abc@xyz.com"
  virtual_network_type = "Internal"
  sku_name             = "Developer_1"

  virtual_network_configuration {
    subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.apisubnet.id
  }

  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.api-pip.id
}


resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi" {
  name                = "azdlgleuw-apim-apimgmjah-001"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "sharat-api"
  path                = "extranet/v1"
  protocols           = ["https"]  
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "example" {
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sharatapimgmntapi.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base />
    <set-backend-service base-url="https://azure-api-sharatapigw-001.azurewebsites.net/api" />
  </inbound>
</policies>
XML
}

Output:



the strange part is I already had nsg connected with my subnet before i went for the APIM deployment and it gave me the that error message which i had pasted earlier. Not sure why i got that one.

Have you checked the location constraint as well? @SharatBhaskar

all resources are in one location. That's why its bit strange. On the other day everything was working as expected. Nothing was changed on either at Azure level or at the code level. Somehow next day it started throwing this error message.

So may be the deployment was saved from before day so when you are trying to implement and run the same one its throwing an error. Instead of deploying it again, import it into current terraform state file. @SharatBhaskar

I manually deleted it from the Azure cloud portal itself, and created a new directory. Still its creating a problem. I could have tried deleting with terraform destroy but it would have taken a lot of time.

In that case delete terraform.tfstate file and try deploying it. @SharatBhaskar
